# Assign 'flight' to a logged-in/ registered user?

Tags: c#, sql, database, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a small ASP.NET MVC4 project in Visual Studio 2013 that utilises the Razor syntax. It's a website for a fictitious private jet hire company.

Currently in my website I have:

- A fully functioning `log-in/ register` feature (allows users to log in/ register with the website)
- Database with all users that are registered (only the `admin@admin.com` user can see this and is able to `edit/ create new/ delete` users)
- A flights database (which the admin can edit)

Here's a `Gist` of what my project files look like: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3528ab17e13c6d5b2460

Here's what my current `SystemUsers` table looks like:
http://gyazo.com/c5013d885723eae7bf578e01cbe1a39c

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SystemUsers] (
    [Email]        NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Password]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [PasswordSalt] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Surname]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Age]          INT            NOT NULL,
    [MobileNumber] NVARCHAR (12)  NOT NULL,
    [HomeNumber]   NVARCHAR (12)  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Email] ASC)
);
```

and here's what my `FLightsTable` looks like:
http://gyazo.com/891bc17d709bdac4f5bfb443ffe6c5a3

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FlightsTable] (
    [FlightID]        INT           NOT NULL,
    [Departure]       NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Arrival]         NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [NumberOfSeats]   INT           NOT NULL,
    [NumberOfFlights] INT           NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([FlightID] ASC)
);
```

In order to assign a `flight` to a `user` I presume I have to create a new table in my database and store the user's `Email` + the `FlightID`? If so, how would I retrieve this information from **both tables** and place it into my new table?

I want the users to be able to select a flight and book it, meaning the amount of spaces on the flight would decrease.

Where would this action (meaning getting the information from the two tables and storing it into a separate table) be declared? What additional files would I need to create in order to make this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a linking table for flight bookings seems appropriate, with primary keys from the two tables in the many to many relationship. You probably also want other information pertaining to the specific booking in this table, such as number of seats reserved, date reservation was placed, credit card used, discount coupon applied, etc.

You would add rows to this table when a customer books a flight.
You would read rows from this table when showing a customer's bookings or to determine number of seats left on a flight (something like: `availableSeats = Flight.NumberOfSeats - bookings.Where(b => b.FlightId == Flight.FlightId).Select(b => b.NumberOfSeats).Sum();`).
You would update rows in this table when a customer wants to modify / cancel a booking, or when a flight is cancelled.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have some queries when it comes to this solution. How do I make my `third table` contain the two primary keys in the many to many relationship? Would you be able to provide me with an example of how this works? In addition, when the customer wants to make a booking, would it be possible for them to use a dropdown menu which reads the row from the `FlightsTable` and then assign that to their booking (ie the "booking table")? If so, would you be able to link me in the right direction in terms of how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question, exactly. Presumably you know the PK of the user who's logged into the system, and when they choose a flight you know the flight id of the one they selected, right? Then, when they choose some number of seats and click 'book this flight', you add a row to your linking table with the email and flight id, along with the other booking info. This is relatively basic database design, and probably too broad a question to ask on stack overflow...